# Does SharePoint provide a hierarchical search results inside my site collections?

Tags: 2013, search, site-collection, central-administration, search-scope

Sometimes I face scenarios inside my SharePoint server 2013 that I cannot understand. Recently I realize the following inside my SharePoint web applications search scope.

Now I have three site collections as follow:-

- http://servername/
- http://servername/Wiki
- http://servername/Dept

And I rely on the default search managed service created inside my central administration.

Now I noticed this scenario.

- Let say I am inside the home page for my `http://servername/` site collection, and inside the built-in search box, I typed the word “procedures” then I will get results from the three site collections. But if I went to let say to `http://servername/wiki` site collection and I type the same word “procedures” then I will only get results from the current site collection `http://servername/wiki`.
  So not sure what is causing these scenarios, although this is something I found useful but I am trying to understand how SharePoint implements this internally. So does SharePoint search treat `http://servername` site collection a parent site collection and the other 2 site collections as its child, so if I am searching from `http://servername` I will get results from its child `http://servername/wiki` & `http//servername/dept`  ?
  thanks

Comment: It basically adds a `path:yourSiteUrl` to the query, hence the experienced behavior

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you please provide more details what do you exactly mean ?

Comment: @RobertLindgren can you adivce more on your comment please?

Comment: I really do not have the time to explain it further I'm afraid

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks for your brief explanation then ..

Comment: Not really sure what your question is. You've mentioned what you have observed and yes that is what happens. Can you add details about what you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Rothrock i am not trying to solve any thing, but rather i am trying to understand what is the default relation between the site collection URL and the search scope ? now does the search deal with the root site collection for example http://servername/ as a parent to another site collection which have let say this url http://servername/dept/?? i thought that search will deal with these 2 site collections as separate site collections, and will not deal with them as a parent-child hierarchy ?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint search is using KQL (Keyword Query Language) where query like: `author:"john doe"` will return items authored by 'John Doe'. By default SharePoint is using site relative results by adding behind the scenes `path:siteUrl` to return items from the particular site.

You can read more about KQL on the MS site: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx

Comment: so are you saying that path such as "_http://servername/_" will cover site collection which have its url as  "_http://servername/dept_"  ???

Comment: Not sure about that, it may be that path limits to the particular site collection you might need to do something like: path:servername OR path:servername/dept.